# How to increase height of custom ActionBar in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

How can i increase height of android ActionBar? I am using custom actionbar from this link
http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

and an image is attached also what i am looking for?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: if you are making a custom ActionBar you should be using Toolbar as that is better suited for customizing

Comment: In your example, simply increase the height of the RelativeLayout. It's actually 50dp. Bring it to 64dp or whatever you like. Maybe, `wrap_content` will be enough.

Comment: @Der Golem, I tried that its strange it did not work...

Comment: @Der Golem, I was missing android:background="@color/light_blue" in relative layout... thanks.. it worked.

Answer (score 9):

To change   height of ActionBar you can create a new file **themes.xml** in your res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
<style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
</style> 
</resources>
```

set this Theme to your Activity:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.FixedSize"
```

Comment: eclipse giving error : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'

Comment: <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item> giving error

Comment: Also getting the " No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarSize'" error in eclipse